# Using an old router as a Wifi receiver appears to cause network disruption

Tags: wireless-networking, router, dd-wrt

I'm currently using an old router that I flashed with DD-WRT a few years ago, and set it up to act as a wireless receiver. I got it working and connected to the WiFi network, so that when you connect a device to it using an Ethernet cable, it also has access to the network.

My machine is Windows 8, MSI Z97 using the onboard Ethernet adapter, my brother's machine is Windows 7, using a super old Netgear Wireless card, as for the router, I'll have to have a look when I get home.

However, I've lately discovered that this setup appears to be causing connection issues for other clients on the network. I've noticed high ping times (between 200-3000ms) on my machine and my brother's machine while we were playing games. These spikes occur at the same time on both machines, and usually resolve themselves within 30 seconds.

This has only been happening since I started using the router on my new computer. I am wondering if this is because of a potential address collision, but I wouldn't expect it to happen every 10 minutes if it was something like an address collision.

The router itself is set up to use the primary router as a DHCP server, and is on the same subnet as the primary router. The router is not rebroadcasting the WiFi network, it is purely allowing access through the physical ports.

Is this something that is debuggable/fixable or should I just bite the bullet and get a proper wireless card?

Comment: I just *knew* that someone would ask about the router model. I'll have a look when I get home and update my question.

Comment: Given wireless cards can be had for less than $10, the time wasted on trying to figure this out would probably have covered it.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of possibilities.

The most likely one is that there is another device which is using the same frequency and taking out the available bandwidth for short periods.   This could be anything from a microwave to baby monitors to other WIFI devices.

It is also possible that something on the network is causing a burst of traffic over the wifi network and consuming the bandwidth.

It could also be that the devices need to (briefly) send a lot of packets - possibly even small ones -  and the router can't cope with the volume of packets and is queuing them.

It is unlikely the problem relates to IP address or routing issues.

Answer (score -2):

You may not have the best version of DD-WRT installed for your router.

DD-WRT is extremely buggy and error-prone in my experience with it.

You may want to explore their forums dedicated to your router's chipset. You may find a version which works better than the one you have.

Without knowing what router you have, I can't offer any advice on which version to flash.

(Had I had 50 rep, I would have commented, thanks for the down vote...)